# Docker: unauthorized: please use personal access token to login

Tags: docker

Good morning guys, I can't access the terminal in my account:
Command:

```bash
docker login
```

```
Error response from daemon: Get "https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/": unauthorized: please use personal access token to login
```

I put the correct id and correct password. Nothing and nothing. I tried several times until I found the solution below. Maybe there's a better alternative. But for next is my problem occurred.

Answer (score 2):

You must set up the docker PAT (Personal Access Token) first with `Read/Write/Delete` [permissions](https://hub.docker.com/settings/security).
Then give that access token instead password

```
docker login registry.example.com -u <your_username> -p <your_personal_access_token>
```

Comment: Thank you dush88c about this solution. I think this is a universal solution for most remote repository.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, if 2FA is enabled, you must use a personal access token instead of a password. You can refer to this [instruction](https://devcoops.com/docker-error-response-from-daemon-unauthorized-please-use-personal-access-token-to-login/) for specific steps.

Answer (score 0):

Run the following command in your terminal

```
docker login
```

Afterwards you will be promoted to input your username then password.
Try and input your PAT(Personal Access Token) instead of your actual docker password.

Answer (score -1):

Good morning guys.

I tried to access my docker account through the terminal, got the error:

```
Error response from daemon: Get "https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/": unauthorized: please use personal access token to login.
```

I tried to change the password it wasn't either.

```
I removed the "Two-factor authentication" I was able to login without problem.
```

That was the quickest solution I did, it solved. Maybe the next one will have a similar problem, here's my example.

Comment: That's not a good option and highly unsecured your personal account from web access.
Don't remove 2-FA or MFA, add PTA instead